# Обращение к вложенным структурам в шаблонах Django.

Tags: python, django, шаблонизаторы, django-template

Возникла вот такая проблема с шаблонами Django.

```
    {% for item in group %}
        {{ item.id }}
        {{preview.item.id}}
    {% endfor %}
```

конструкция **{{preview.item.id}}** отказывается работать.

**item** - это объект с полями *name, id* и т.д.
**preview** - это словарь, в котором ключем является значение item.id.

если я вывожу просто

```
{{item.id}}
```

то айдишник выводится, если подставляю в словарь **preview** константу

```
{{preview.1}}
```

то соответственно выводится значение по этому ключу. Но вот в таком случае **{{preview.item.id}}** ничего не работает.

Предположил, что это из-за вложенности. Каким образом можно провернуть такую штуку?

Comment: Не работал с Django, но разве так ({{preview.item.id}}) должно работать?

Ведь мы что делаем - берем preview, у него берем item, а у этого item уже берем id. А item у preview есть?

Еще раз - не работал с django. Попробуйте что-нить типа {{preview.{item.id}}} или {{preview.[item.id]}}

Хотя [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/52815/) пишут, про "отсутствие обращения к словарю по ключу находящемуся в переменной".

Может быть и нельзя...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), в который передавать item.id, например:

```
{% get_preview item.id %}
```

И который вернет необходимый preview.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_preview(id):
    preview = какая-то выбрка
    return preview
```